# Generating dynamic form with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic

I'm having a problem generating form dynamically.
This is my code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').on('click',function(){
            $('<p><input type="text"  id="testo"/><input type="button" name="remove" id="remove" Value="rimuovi" /></p>').appendTo(content);

        });

        //$('#remove').on('click', function() { 
            //$(this).parents('p').remove();
        //});
        $( 'body' ).on( "click", "#remove", function() {

            console.log( $( this ).text() );

        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <p>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Input Value"/>
            <input type ="checkbox"  ></input>
            <input type="button" name="remove" id="remove" Value="rimuovi"></input>
            <input type="button" name="add" id="add" Value="add"></input>
        </p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Adding fields works fine and even the remove button written statically . The problem is with the button "remove" generated by jquery. It doesnt work and doesnt generate any outuput on the console. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#add').on('click', function() {
        $('<p><input type="text"  id="testo"/><input type="button" name="remove" id="remove" Value="rimuovi" /></p>').appendTo(content);

      });

      $(document).on('click', '#remove', function() {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
      });
      $('body').on("click", "#remove", function() {

        console.log($(this).text());

      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
    <input type="checkbox"></input>
    <input type="button" name="remove" id="remove" Value="rimuovi"></input>
    <input type="button" name="add" id="add" Value="add"></input>
  </p>
</div>
```

Here's the code

You need to run the on click on the document for dynamically loaded elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you are using same `id` multiple times. Either use unique `id`s or make it class. see below code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#add').on('click',function(){
                $('<p><input type="text"  id="testo"/><input type="button" name="remove" class="remove" Value="rimuovi" /></p>').appendTo(content);

            });

            //$('#remove').on('click', function() { 
                //$(this).parents('p').remove();
            //});
            $( 'body' ).on( "click", "input[type='button'].remove", function() {

                console.log( $( this ).text() );

            });
  });
```